# How can i make a sprite appear middle of your cursor? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I made a sprite (hitmarker) to appear middle of your mouse when you click on a sprite (egg), but the hitmarker sprite appears at the right bottom of your mouse like this:

[image: My Result]

however, I wanna make it appear like this:

[image: What i wanna make]

I tried `screen.blit(hitmarker, (pygame.mouse.get_pos()))`
but it appears at the right bottom of your mouse.

Source Code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
from millify import millify,prettify

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
music = open("music.txt", "r+")
pygame.mixer.music.load("soundtrack.wav")
x = int(music.read())
WHITE = 255,255,255
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 44)
cpsecond = open("clickpersecond.txt", "r+")
cps = int(cpsecond.read())
baltotal = open("totalbal.txt", "r+")
totalbal = int(baltotal.read())
totalbalM = prettify(totalbal, '.')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
w = 800
h = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tap Simulator')
Loop = True
background = pygame.image.load("Background.jpg")
egg = pygame.image.load("egg.png")
resized_egg = pygame.transform.scale(egg, (282, 352))
text = font.render(f'Your total clicks are {totalbalM}', True, WHITE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)
volume = pygame.image.load("volume.png")
mute = pygame.image.load("mute.png")
resized_volume = pygame.transform.scale(volume, (100, 100))
resized_mute = pygame.transform.scale(mute, (100,100))
icon = pygame.image.load("ico.ico")
hitmarker = pygame.image.load("hitmarker.png")
resized_hitmarker = pygame.transform.scale(hitmarker, (50, 50))

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

while Loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            Loop = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # 1 == left click
                egg_rect = resized_egg.get_rect(topleft = (260,150))
                vol_rect = volume.get_rect(topleft = (700,500))
                if vol_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    x += 1
                    if x > 2:
                        x = 1
                if egg_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    totalbal += cps
                    totalbalM = prettify(totalbal, '.')
                    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
                    if x == 1:
                        screen.blit(resized_volume, (700,500))
                    if x == 2:
                        screen.blit(resized_mute,(700,500))
                    screen.blit(text, (235,557))
                    screen.blit(resized_egg, (260,150))
                    screen.blit(resized_hitmarker, (pygame.mouse.get_pos()))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    text = font.render(f'Your total clicks are {totalbalM}', True, WHITE)
                    print("Your total clicks are", totalbalM, end="\r")
                    time.sleep(0.07)



    #print(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) #to get mouse pos
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(resized_volume, (700,500))
    if x == 0:
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))# [...] draw something different
    elif x == 1:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        screen.blit(resized_volume, (700,500))
    elif x == 2:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        screen.blit(resized_mute,(700,500))
    screen.blit(text, (235,557))    
    screen.blit(resized_egg, (260,150))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

with open("totalbal.txt", "w") as baltotal:
    baltotal.write(str(totalbal))
baltotal.close

with open("music.txt", "w") as music:
    music.write(str(x))
music.close
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please include relevant source code in the question body instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: All right, done.

Answer (score 3):

`pygame.Surface.blit` takes the destination position as the top-left corner of the surface you want to blit. To move the center of the surface to the position, you simply need to offset the position by half of the surface's width. This way the center of the image aligns with the original position.

So in pseudo-code you want to do `screen.blit(cursor, pygame.mouse.get_pos() - cursor.get_size() / 2)`.

Comment: I get this error, what do i do? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: Write the vector math out, like I said the code in the question is pseudo-code.

Comment: i don't know what do you mean by "Write the vector math out" but i did it like this `screen.blit(hitmarker, pygame.mouse.get_pos() - hitmarker.get_size() / 2)` and it still says the same thing

Answer (score 0):

this is the way that worked for me.

First you need to find de center of the image, i did it like this:

```
self.mid_height = (self.image.get_width()/2)
self.mid_width = (self.image.get_height()/2)
```

this way i store the middle value of the height and width of the sprite or image, then, i separete the two values that returns te get_pos() function in two variables:

```
self.cursor_x, self.cursor_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

and substract each value of middle height and middle width to the position values of the cursor:

```
self.cursor_center_x = (self.cursor_x - self.mid_height)
self.cursor_center_y = (self.cursor_y - self.mid_width)
```

then i stored again the new values in the final variable:

```
self.cursor_pos = self.cursor_center_x, self.cursor_center_y
```

and last i used that final tuple in the blit function:

```
self.screen.blit(self.image, self.cursor_pos)
```